# Sharing Internet from Pc connected to Wifi to Ethernet to a router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, ethernet, sharing

I live in a building where to get Wifi you need to pay for a voucher code which works on a single device and stores its MAC for future auto connectivity. I thought i would get that voucher for my Laptop/PC, connect it to wifi and share the internet to ethernet port and then plug in a tp link wifi repeater in **Access Point (AP)** mode to it which has a **LAN port**. The problem is that when i make a bridge between Wifi adapter and Ethernet Adapter, my laptop gets disconnected from the internet. When I turn on ICS on the Wifi adapter there is still no internet on the AP. Here is what I did;

1. After turning on ICS, accessed  web gui of my Access point and set
   the following in the IP configuration form;
2. Ip address: 192.168.137.2
3. Gateway: 192.168.137.1 (same as ipv4 of ethernet)
4. Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
5. Primary Dns:10.10.0.1 (same as of connected wifi to be shared)
   Still there was no internet, however after putting primary Dns same as gateway on AP's settings, the first page of Web Gui named 'network map' shows a Globe saying 'internet connected' even though there is no internet on the connected wireless clients.

I downloaded a cracked version of connectify pro and started its wired routed mode on router access and that gave internet connection to the clients connected to AP. However now i can't access the Ap's Web Gui (as long as connectify is connected) even after typing in the gateway. Connectify also changed Ipv4 of ethernet to **192.168.241.1** and this is also the gateway as can be seen from the clients connected to the AP.  This means that there is some problem in ip settings which i can't seem to find and connectify changes it to give internet access. Still i believe it can't have access to the Web Gui of AP and so whatever it changes is in Windows itself. Now i need to keep running connectify pro as disconnecting it stops the internet share and reverts back ethernet ipv4 to auto. I don't want to use this cracked software and want to manually set up this share. Does anyone has any idea on what i am getting wrong?

Comment: Restart your laptop, connect it and share Wireless to one other Wireless device.  Does that work?  I am not certain but that may be the limit of what you can do.

Comment: Are you okay with your extra devices having internet over wifi? or do they need ethernet? I ask because you might be able to achieve this by starting a hosted network through wifi if your wireless lan adapter in your pc supports it.

Comment: My wireless Lan adapter does support it. "Connectify" and "My Public Wifi" both applications can make hotspot while i am connected to the Wifi. The only problem with that is the random disconnection of internet and would only resume when i close and restart the applications plus the low signal strength. This TP LINK WL 850RE has good signal range and using ICS on windows will automatically make my laptop a router without the need of applications running in the background. Plus the Tp link only works when i use connectify pro's wired router sharing mode and not windows inbuilt ICS and nowIstuck